# separar cadena de texto

Tags: javascript

Buenas perdonen mi ignorancia y mi poca facilidad de entender el javascript pero es que tengo un gran problema, quisiera separar una cadena de texto de modo que al separarlo la otra parte quede al lado abajo como si existiera un "/n" o un br/>
este es mi codigo:

```
       function _drawAGT_RiskTable(CanvasId, ArrayObj, ArrayPoints, isIntPoints, ArraySettings) {
var _elem = $('#' + CanvasId);
var _a = ArrayObj;
var _b = ArrayPoints;

var _s = (ArraySettings === undefined) ? {
    gridWidth: 75,
    fontSizeScale: 12,
    fontFamily: 'Arial',
    distanceX: 0,
    distanceY: 0,
    extraWidth: 0,
    extraHeight: 0,
    array: [],
    rangeX: 0,
    rangeY: 0,
    m: [],
    fontSizeScaleTable: '12',
} : ArraySettings;

$.each(_a, function (i, v) { _s.array.push(v.X); });
_s.rangeX = Math.max.apply(Math, _s.array) + 1;

_s.array = [];

$.each(_a, function (i, v) { _s.array.push(v.Y); });

_s.rangeY = Math.max.apply(Math, _s.array) + 1;

_s.m = _generateMatrix(_s.rangeX, _s.rangeY, _a);

_elem.attr({ width: _s.extraWidth + _s.gridWidth + _s.distanceX + (_s.gridWidth * _s.rangeY) + 'px', height: _s.extraHeight + _s.gridWidth + _s.distanceY + (_s.gridWidth * _s.rangeX) + 'px' })

for (var i = 0; i < _s.rangeX; i++) // dranwing grid
{
    for (var j = 0; j < _s.rangeY; j++) {
        _elem.drawRect({
            layer: true,
            bringToFront: false,
            strokeStyle: '#000',
            strokeWidth: _s.m[i][j].StrokeWidth,
            fillStyle: _s.m[i][j].ReferenceColor,
            x: _s.gridWidth * (j + 1) + _s.distanceX, y: _s.gridWidth * (i + 1) + _s.distanceY,
            width: _s.gridWidth,
            height: _s.gridWidth,
        });
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < _s.rangeX; i++)  // dranwing text scale
{
    for (var j = 0; j < _s.rangeY; j++) {
        if (j == 0) {
            _drawCustomText(_matrixTextY(_a)[i], _elem, _s, i, j, isIntPoints, _s.fontSizeScaleTable);
        }
        if (i == 0 && j > 0) {
            _drawCustomText(_matrixTextX(_a)[j], _elem, _s, i, j, isIntPoints, _s.fontSizeScaleTable);
        }
    }//end-for-2
}//end-for-1


$.each(_b, function (i, v) { _drawPoint(v, _elem, _s); });
//_drawLastScale();

function _drawLastScale() {
    _elem.drawText({
        layer: true,
        fillStyle: '#00a',
        fontSize: _s.fontSizeScale + 'px',
        x: _s.distanceX + (_s.gridWidth + _s.gridWidth / 2 - _s.fontSizeScale / 2),
        y: _s.distanceY + (_s.gridWidth + _s.gridWidth / 2 + _s.fontSizeScale / 2),
        fontFamily: _s.fontFamily,
        text: _s.rangeX,
        rotate: 0,
    });
    _elem.drawText({
        layer: true,
        fillStyle: '#00a',
        fontSize: _s.fontSizeScale + 'px',
        x: _s.distanceX + (_s.gridWidth * _s.rangeY + _s.gridWidth / 2),
        y: _s.distanceY + (_s.gridWidth + _s.gridWidth / 2 - _s.fontSizeScale / 2),
        fontFamily: _s.fontFamily,
        text: _s.rangeY,
        rotate: 0,
    });
}

function _findEqualPoint(_obj) {
    var ep = 0;
    var i = 0;
    while (_b[i].Id != _obj.Id) {
        if ((_b[i].X) === _obj.X && (_b[i].Y === _obj.Y))
            ep = ep + 1;

        i = i + 1;
    }

    return ep;
}

function _findEqualPoints(_obj) {
    var points = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < _b.length; i++)  // dranwing text scale
    {
        if ((_b[i].X) === _obj.X && (_b[i].Y === _obj.Y) && (_b[i].Id != _obj.Id))
            points = points + 1;
    }
    return points;
}

function _getXPoint(_pointX, _radio, _equalPoint, _equalPoints) {

    var y = 0;
    var _grados = 0;
    var _radianes = 0;

    if (isIntPoints == "True")
        x = _s.distanceX + (_s.gridWidth * (_pointX) + _s.gridWidth);
    else
        x = _s.distanceX + (_s.gridWidth * (_pointX) + _s.gridWidth) - (_s.gridWidth / 2);

    if (_equalPoints > 1) {
        _grados = (360 / _equalPoints) * _equalPoint;
        _radianes = (_grados * Math.PI) / 180;
        if (_equalPoints > 7) {
            if (_equalPoint <= 2 && _equalPoints > 12) {
                _grados = (360 / 3) * _equalPoint;
                _radianes = (_grados * Math.PI) / 180;
                x = 8 * Math.cos(_radianes) + x;
            }
            else if (_equalPoints > 12) {
                _grados = (360 / (_equalPoints - 3)) * _equalPoint;
                _radianes = (_grados * Math.PI) / 180;
                x = 25 * Math.cos(_radianes) + x;
            }
            else
                x = 25 * Math.cos(_radianes) + x;
            //x = x + 10;
        }
        else {
            x = _radio * Math.cos(_radianes) + x;

        }
    }

    return x;
}

function _getYPoint(_pointY, _radio, _equalPoint, _equalPoints) {

    var y = 0;
    var _grados = 0;
    var _radianes = 0;

    if (isIntPoints == "True")
        y = _s.distanceY + (_s.gridWidth * (_s.rangeX - _pointY) + _s.gridWidth * 2) - (_s.gridWidth);
    else
        y = _s.distanceY + (_s.gridWidth * (_s.rangeX - _pointY) + _s.gridWidth * 2) - (_s.gridWidth / 2);

    if (_equalPoints > 1) {
        _grados = (360 / _equalPoints) * _equalPoint;
        _radianes = (_grados * Math.PI) / 180;
        if (_equalPoints > 7) {
            if (_equalPoint <= 2 && _equalPoints > 12) {
                _grados = (360 / 3) * _equalPoint;
                _radianes = (_grados * Math.PI) / 180;
                y = (8 * (-1)) * Math.sin(_radianes) + y;
            }
            else if (_equalPoints > 12) {
                _grados = (360 / (_equalPoints - 3)) * _equalPoint;
                _radianes = (_grados * Math.PI) / 180;
                y = (25 * (-1)) * Math.sin(_radianes) + y;
            }
            else
                y = (25 * (-1)) * Math.sin(_radianes) + y;
        }
        else {
            y = (_radio * (-1)) * Math.sin(_radianes) + y;

        }
        // y = y-10
    }

    return y;
}

function _drawPoint(_obj, _elem, _s) {/// aqui se generan los circulos del canvas
    _s.fontSizeScale = 10;
    var scaleRadio = 15;
    var _pointX = _obj.X;
    var _pointY = _obj.Y;
    var _equalPoint = _findEqualPoint(_obj);
    var _equalPoints = _findEqualPoints(_obj);
    var parrafo = _obj.Text;
    var acumulada;
    //var txt = function () {
    //    while(){
    //    if (parrafo.length() > 20) {

    //    }
    //    }
    //}
    console.log(txt);
    _elem.addLayer({
        type: 'arc',
        name: 'arc' + _obj.Id,
        fillStyle: 'rgba(0,89,179,.6)',
        radius: _s.fontSizeScale,
        x: _getXPoint(_pointX, scaleRadio, _equalPoint, _equalPoints),// funcion donde se genera la posicion X donde se va ubicar el circulo generado
        //x: _s.distanceX + (_s.gridWidth * (_pointX) + _s.gridWidth) - (_s.gridWidth / 2),
        y: _getYPoint(_pointY, scaleRadio, _equalPoint, _equalPoints),//funcion donde se genera la posicion Y donde se va ubicar el circulo generado
        //y: _s.distanceY + (_s.gridWidth * (_s.rangeX - _pointY) + _s.gridWidth * 2) - (_s.gridWidth / 2),
        mouseover: function (layer) {
            if (_elem.getLayer('text_rect' + _obj.Id).width == 0) {
                _elem.getLayer('text_rect' + _obj.Id).width = _elem.getLayer('text_details' + _obj.Id).width * 2 + _s.fontSizeScale * 4;

            }
            if (_elem.getLayer('text_rect' + _obj.Id).height == 0) {
                _elem.getLayer('text_rect' + _obj.Id).height = _elem.getLayer('text_details' + _obj.Id).height / 2;
            }
            _elem.getLayer('text_details' + _obj.Id).visible = true;
            _elem.getLayer('text_rect' + _obj.Id).visible = true;
        },
        mouseout: function (layer) {
            _elem.getLayer('text_details' + _obj.Id).visible = false;
            _elem.getLayer('text_rect' + _obj.Id).visible = false;
        },
    }).addLayer({
        type: 'text',
        fontStyle: 'bold',
        fontFamily: _s.fontFamily,
        name: 'text_id' + _obj.Id,
        fillStyle: '#fff',
        x: _elem.getLayer('arc' + _obj.Id).x,
        y: _elem.getLayer('arc' + _obj.Id).y,
        text: _obj.Id,
        fontSize: _s.fontSizeScale + 'px',
    }).addLayer({//aqui se crea el tootlp
        type: 'rectangle',
        visible: false,
        width: 0,height: 0,                        
        name: 'text_rect' + _obj.Id,
        fillStyle: 'rgba(0,0,0,.6)',
        cornerRadius: 10,
        x: _elem.getLayer('arc' + _obj.Id).x + _s.fontSizeScale,
        y: _elem.getLayer('arc' + _obj.Id).y - _s.fontSizeScale * 3,
    }).addLayer({//aqui van los datos con los que llena el tootlp
        type: 'text',
        visible: false,            
        fontFamily: _s.fontFamily,
        name: 'text_details' + _obj.Id,           
        addClass: 'one',
        fillStyle: '#76eec6',//'#fff',
        x: _elem.getLayer('arc' + _obj.Id).x + _s.fontSizeScale,
        y: _elem.getLayer('arc' + _obj.Id).y - _s.fontSizeScale * 3,
        text: _obj.Text+ '\n X: ' + _obj.X + ' ; Y: ' + _obj.Y + '',
        fontSize: _s.fontSizeScale + 'px',
    }).drawLayers();

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('[name= "text_details' + _obj.Id + '"]').tooltip();
    });

}
exportIMG();
```

}
este seria mi json donde envio los datos que recibe esa función:

try {
        if (scales) {
            _drawAGT_RiskTable(
                'mycanvas', jQuery.parseJSON(scales), jQuery.parseJSON(risks), isintpoints
                );
        }
    } catch (ex) { }

y este mi html:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                <canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
            </div>
```

Comment: Deberías incluir el mínimo de líneas de código necesarias para lograr el resultado que estás buscando.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes modificar las propiedades de estilo del `tooltip(...)`.

Ejemplo

```js
$(function () {

 // Modificar el estilo a través del método open:
 $('#div1').tooltip({
  open: function (event, ui) {
   ui.tooltip.css("max-width", "800px");
  }
 });

 // Modificar el estilo a través de una clase:
 $('#div2').tooltip({
  classes: {
   "ui-tooltip-content": "ui-tootip-width"
  }
 });
});
```

```css
.ui-tootip-width {
 width: 800px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="div1" title="
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.">hello!!
</div>
<div id="div2" title="
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.">Word!!
</div>
```

Comment: te agradezco por la respuesta pero mi problema no creo que valla de la mano del css porque todo es creado con javascript voy añadir el código completo para que lo veas

Comment: cambias totalmente la pregunta.